# Why is this regexp query not returning any results?

Tags: mysql, sql

Good day

I have a field that have rows looking like

```
BBB-888-8557ZZV-003.XYZ
BBB-999-8787ZZV-00D.XYZ
```

I need to find (and replace after I confirmed that my select returns the correct rows :)) all records that match the regex:

```
/-\d\d[A-Z]/g
```

Hence all fields that have a minus sign followed by two digits followed by an alphabet letter.

I also only need to filter out the fields that have 999 in them.

I tried the following SQL but it returns no results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `track` 
WHERE (
pod LIKE  "BBB-999%"
AND pod
REGEXP  '/-\d\d[A-Z]/g'
)
```

Also, what will be a quick why to replace all of these fields once they are found to:

```
BBB-999-8787ZZV-_MARK_D.XYZ
```

Comment: I have given you a solution which can cope with strings of arbitrary length.  Please have a look if you get a chance, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numbers in `mysql` shouls be matched like `[0-9] or [[:digit:]]` 
`\d` wont work as you expected.  [link](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70413)

try;

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `track` 
WHERE
pod LIKE  "BBB-999%" and
pod REGEXP  '\-[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{1}'
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `track` 
WHERE
pod LIKE  "BBB-999%" and
pod REGEXP  '\-[[:digit:]]{2}[A-Z]{1}'
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/838e5/21)

*Update the field having `-00[A-Z].XYZ` with `-MARK[A_Z].XYZ`*

1. Then length of the string is varying (from comment)
2. last 8 characters can be either `\-[0-9]{3}.XYZ` or `\-[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{1}.XYZ`

try:

```
UPDATE `track`
SET `pod` = concat(reverse(substr(reverse( `pod` ) from 8)), 'MARK', substr( `pod`  from -5)) 
WHERE
`pod` LIKE  "BBB-999%" and
`pod` REGEXP  '\-0{2}[A-Z]{1}';
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/afa094/1)

Comment: Thanks Praveen, this works 100% How could I now replace all the 00[A-Z] matches with _MARK_[A-Z] in the table?

Comment: Is `pod` value is fixed length data with `xxx-xxx-xxxxxxx-xxx.xxx` pattern??

Comment: Hi Praveen, no it is not. It will always start with BBB-999- and then will have a combination of numbers and letters followed by '\-[0-9]{3}' or '\-[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{1}' followed by .XYZ I need to replace all the 00 in the ones that your regexp finds with _MARK_ Hope this makes sense :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `CONCAT()` function to get the replacement in the output, after restricting with your query.

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(pod, 1, LENGTH(pod) - LOCATE('-', REVERSE(pod)) + 1),
              '_MARK_D.XYZ')
FROM `track`
WHERE
(
    pod LIKE  "BBB-999%"
    AND pod REGEXP  '-[0-9][0-9][A-Z]'
)
```

For some reason, I needed to use `[0-9]` in the MySQL regex to get it to work.

Click the link below for a running demo:

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc2d1e/18)

If you want actually change the values in the `pod` column you can try an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE `track`
SET pod = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(pod, 1, LENGTH(pod) - LOCATE('-', REVERSE(pod)) + 1),
                 '_MARK_D.XYZ')
WHERE
(
    pod LIKE  "BBB-999%"
    AND pod REGEXP  '-[0-9][0-9][A-Z]'
)
```

Comment: I got it working now.  The trick is to use `[0-9]` to represent any number in the regular expression.  Please try the SQL Fiddle to convice yourself.

Comment: Hi @tim-biegeleisen, thanks this is working now, How can I replace the values found by the select inside the actual table and not just have it displayed in the output?